# Is it possible to set Mathematica output to be in InputForm by default?

Tags: output-formatting

Mma's output cells are by default in StandardForm. While this has obvious advantages, sometimes it can get annoying, for example when I wish to copy paste the output. When this happens, I usually manually right-click the cell and convert it to InputForm.

But is it possible to set these output cells to be in InputForm by default? Because under `Preferences` -> `Evaluation` -> `Format type of new output cells` I can only see three possibilities: `StandardForm`, `TraditionalForm` and `OutputForm`.

Comment: Why not just use Copy As > Input Text, either from the Edit menu or the (left-click) context menu?

Comment: @m_goldberg First, because, for example, the constant Pi gets copied as `\[Pi]` this way, as opposed to converting it to InputForm, when it gets copied as `Pi`. Second, because I was wondering if there is any auto solution, that wouldn't require any extra clicking...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`$PrePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html) to achieve this:

```
$PrePrint = InputForm;
```

Now every output will be preprocessed by `InputForm` before it is printed.
Use

```
$PrePrint =.;
```

to restore the default behavior.
You could also use [`$Post`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Post.html) instead of `$PrePrint`. However, when `$Post` is used you'll get `Null` as an output when there normally is no output, e.g. if the input ended with `;`.

Comment: Many thanks! Out of curiosity: what's the difference between `$PrePrint` and `$Post`? Because from what I read in the documentation, they seem pretty much the same...

Comment: @gaazkam I thing `$PrePrint` is the better choice. Please see my edit why.

Answer (score 5):

I think a cleaner way to achieve this would be:

```
SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> InputForm];
```

Comment: This method produces an odd placing of the output ([example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xMstg.png)), as it's printed before the `Out`s, which appear empty. Nevertheless +1.

Comment: How do I undo this?

Comment: @Kvothe `SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> StandardForm]` to undo.