# Elimination of "1" in HoldComplete

Tags: evaluation, output, hold, display

`HoldComplete[2 3 3]` will return `HoldComplete[2 3 3]`.
`HoldComplete[b a]` will return `HoldComplete[b a]`.

Everything works fine here, no replacement rules called, no evaluation done, the `Flat` attribute didn't apply.

but things get weird when we evaluate `HoldComplete[a 2 1 2]`:

The desired result shall be `HoldComplete[a 2 1 2]` as no modification should be done here, however, the result is `HoldComplete[a 2 2]`, it seems that the `1` is magically omitted as it's not important here in multiplication!

How could this happen? Is this a bug? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the `FullForm`. The `1` is not displayed, but it is in fact there.

Comment: Nope~ It's not there. Once you evaluate it, it's not there: `HoldComplete[a 2 1 2] // FullForm` returns `HoldComplete[Times[a, 2, 1, 2]]` while do the same to the evaluation result of `HoldComplete[a 2 1 2]` would give `HoldComplete[Times[a, 2, 2]]`

Comment: I think this makes things even wierder......

Comment: You are not applying `FullForm` to the actual evaluation result. You are applying it to *some text* in the output cell.  That is not the same thing. Assign the result to a variable.

Comment: Oh, good point! But how can I let it display just like the way I entered?

Comment: It seems that it does display the `1` in InputForm, so if this is important, you could set the default output to be in input form ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59409/discussion-between-wjx-and-szabolcs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you see in the output cell is just a *visualization* of the actual result of the evaluation. When [working with the FrontEnd](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfTheWolframSystem.html) the default `FormatType` of the output stream is [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm.html) what means that [`FormatValues`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32314/280) rules for `StandardForm` will automatically be [applied](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LowLevelInputAndOutputRules.html) to the actual output *before* sending it to the FrontEnd (in order to produce a [*typeset expression*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114401/280)):

```
Options["stdout", FormatType]
```

> ```
> {FormatType -> StandardForm}
> ```

```
MakeBoxes[HoldComplete[a 2 1 2], StandardForm]
```

> ```
> RowBox[{"HoldComplete", "[", 
>   RowBox[{"a", " ", "2", " ", "2"}], "]"}]
> ```

You can switch to purely textual `InputForm` display mode by wrapping your input by `InputForm`:

```
In[3]:=
HoldComplete[a 2 1 2]//InputForm    

Out[3]//InputForm=
HoldComplete[a*2*1*2]
```

You can also check the actual result of the evaluation by requesting it from the history:

```
In[4]:= HoldComplete[a 2 1 2];

In[5]:= % // FullForm

Out[5]//FullForm= 
HoldComplete[Times[a,2,1,2]]
```

---

Related:

- [Conversion of expressions by the FrontEnd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5617685/590388)
- [Prevent graphics render inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32296/280)
- [Is it possible to set Mathematica output to be in InputForm by default?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77224/280)
- [How to make tabs aligned in Print?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144350/280)
- [Mathematica's Format Pseudofunction](http://weaklyreachable.blogspot.ru/2012/09/mathematicas-format-pseudofunction.html)
- [Understanding evaluation and typesetting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114305/280)
- [Understanding the output formatting of held forms](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124314/280)

Comment: What is `"stdout"`?  I've never seen that before.

Comment: @QuantumDot It's the name of the standard output stream. By default [`$Output`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$Output.html) lists it as `OutputStream["stdout", 1]`. But it is possible to refer to it directly as to `"stdout"`.

Comment: +1 nice explanation!

Comment: Nice explanation! Thanks~